# Fetch address not being aligned with word boundary in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

```
.data
vector_A: .float 5.2, 7.1, 2.0      
vector_B: .float 15.4, 3.5, 11.5
   
result: .float 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

.text
li $t0, 0   #initialize i
la $s2, result  #equivalent to *s0=&result[0]; in C



##################################################################################
#write code to load each element from array vector_B, scale by Co-factor= 0.8,   #
# and then store back at the corresponding original memory adresses of vector_B  #
##################################################################################




##########################################################################
loop:
       ###################################################
la $s0 vector_A  #load starting address of array vector_A into s0 #
la $s1, vector_B    #load starting address of array vector_B into s1 #
       ###################################################  

bge $t0, 3, print

#STEP 1:
#implement if statements

#recommended method as follows:
#set $t_ equal to 1 if $t0=1 else set to 0 #hint:may use seq
seq $t1, $t0, 1
#set $t_ equal to 1 if $t0=2 else set to 0
seq $t1, $t0, 2
#set $t_ equal to 1 if $t0=3 else set to 0
seq $t1, $t0, 3

beqz $t1, skip1
#set j and k
skip1:
li $a1, 1
li $a2, 2

beq $t0, 1 skip2

skip2:
li $a1, 0
li $a2, 2

beq $t0, 2 skip3

skip3:
li $a1, 0
li $a2, 1

################################################################
#Similarly set the if, else conditions for the other two       #
#conditions of j, k as in the C code using different labels    #
################################################################



#STEP 2:
#load the two numbers from arrays vector_A and vector_B into coprocessors (i.e. floating point registers)

sub $a3, $a1, $a2 #use this as k index

add $s0, $s0, $a1
l.s $f0, 0($s0)

add $s0, $s0, $a3
l.s $f1, 0($s0)
#do previous 4 instructions again but for $s1 (array_B)

add $s1, $s1, $a1
l.s $f2, 0($s1)

add $s1, $s1, $a3
l.s $f3, 0($s1)


#STEP 3:
#perform the math
mul.s $f10, $f0, $f3
mul.s $f11, $f1, $f2
sub.s $f15, $f10, $f11


#FINAL STEP:
#store the results into the results array
s.s $f15, result 
addi $s2, $s2, 4 #increment results register to the next index
```

Sorry for how much code there is here, the error I am getting is that at the line
l.s $f1, 0($s0)
I'm receiving a fetch address being out of word bounds, in the code I increment s0 by the difference of a2 and a1(as instructed per assignment), and then reference that value into f1. I do not understand why I am receiving an error for this line as the referenced point is at 0($s0) so I would assume it could not be out of boundary. Any help you can offer is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Get to know where your data lives.  For MARS there is a data view and a symbols view, among other properties you can use.  You can examine the data layout during execution when it stops before the first instruction.  During single step debugging, if the value in `$s0` is odd or out of bounds, you'll be able to tell, and then it is a matter tracing earlier in the instruction stream to find out who/what instruction provided the bad value (and sometimes this is a process needs to be repeated to find the actual culprit).

Comment: "conditions of j, k as in the C code using different labels" May we see the C code? That would help to diagnose the problem here

Answer (score 1):

When I executed your code, $a3 had the value -1 (0xffffffff) and this value added with the $s0 resulted in $s0 having the value 0x1000ffff which is not in word boundary. addresses are 4 bytes in mips and if you are trying to load into an address which is not divisible by 4 you get the boundary error. I did not look at your complete code assignment however if you are trying to use addresses make sure that they are incremented and decremented by numbers that are divisible by 4.